# Facebook Page Likes over time

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm not the owner of a facebook page (eg. TESLA) but I'm trying to use graph api to get the number of user that liked the pages over time. Based on graphi api documentation (insight/page_fans), I'm just getting empty json documents. Any ideas how I can get this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only two page-related metrics are available publicly, page_fans_country and page_storytellers_by_country.

Everything else is only accessible to an admin user of the page, resp. using a page access token.

You can not get the data you want for pages you do not have admin access to.